# Using single dataset how to create multiple tablix reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Is it possible to create multiple tablix reports using single dataset in ssrs.if it is possible please can u guide me

Comment: 1. Right click on the Tablix you made
2. Select Tablix Properties
3. On the first page under general, look for the box dataset name
4. Make sure that is set to the dataset you want to use!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to drag-and-drop or add multiple tablixes to the report grid.  After that, you can right click on the tablix (click in the top left hand corner of the tablix) and click properties to specify which dataset it uses.

**To associate a data region with a dataset by using properties**

1. In Design view, right-click the data region and then click Tablix Properties, Chart Properties, or Gauge Panel Properties.
2. In Dataset name, select a dataset from the drop-down list.